# Laravel Curl to send multiple SMS

Tags: laravel

I am developing a small script and I am bit messed up.
I'm parsing csv file as list of phone Nos to receive bulk SMS notification.
The csv file record is in the form of 1 phone No column contains all phone Nos
the app is first allow the user to upload csv file then it shows them to the user in order to prepare a text message to be sent.
The app is working but no SMS received.
I wish if some help me with phone No array.

(code from comment 1)

```
if (count($data) > 0) {
  if ($request->has('header')) {
    $csv_header_fields = [];
    foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
      $csv_header_fields[] = $key;
    }
  }
  $csv_data = $data;
  $csv_data_file = CsvData::create([
     'csv_filename' => request->file('csv_file')->getClientOriginalName(),
     'csv_header' => $request->has('header'),
     'csv_data' => json_encode($data)
     ]); 
} else {
  return redirect()->back(); 
}
```

(code from comment 2)

```
$json = array();
$mobile_phone = $data;
$message = $notes ." \Hello";
$mobile_phone_array = str_split($mobile_phone);
$sms = array( 'number' => $mobile_phone, 'message' => $message, 'key' => '123' );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '10.192.100.180/NoranAPI/default.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($sms));
$result_sms = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: if (count($data) > 0) {
            if ($request->has('header')) {
$csv_header_fields = [];
foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
$csv_header_fields[] = $key;
                }
            }
$csv_data = $data;
$csv_data_file = CsvData::create([
'csv_filename' => $request->file('csv_file')->getClientOriginalName(),
 'csv_header' => $request->has('header'),
 'csv_data' => json_encode($data)
 ]);
  } else {   return redirect()->back();  }

Comment: '''


       $json = array();
 $mobile_phone = $data;
    $message = $notes ." \Hello";
    $mobile_phone_array = str_split($mobile_phone);
   
$sms = array(
'number' => $mobile_phone,
'message' => $message,
'key' => '123'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://10.192.100.180/NoranAPI/default.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($sms));
$result_sms = curl_exec($ch);
'''

Comment: under your post, there is a link named "edit". You should better use ot to add your code inside the question, formatted properly (with the {] icon) and then delete your 2 comments listing code...

Comment: I tried it many time, it wont let me

Comment: @salehzwy Go to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58358063/edit.

Comment: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: @salehzwy So do that?

Comment: So I did and it wont, this site is helpful but it makes it very hard to get your point thought.

Comment: looks good now.